# Invoking sh or bat generically from a Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on a pipeline script that will execute on both Windows and Linux. For both systems, I need to invoke the same command (for example `python -V`). I can accomplish this with a helper function:

```
def genericsh(cmd) {
    if (isUnix()) {
        sh cmd
    }
    else {
        bat cmd
    }
}
```

Then in my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
genericsh 'python -V'
```

This seems to work okay, however it produces extra `isUnix` noise in the output log for each command executed.

Is there a better way to invoke a command generically across Windows and Linux in a Jenkins pipeline script? If not is there a mechanism for suppressing the isUnix() step tag in the pipeline log?

Answer (score 16):

You could assign isUnix() to a variable early in your script which would mean that you only see that once, not once per external command.

```
env.UNIX = isUnix()
```

then

```
def genericSh(cmd) {
    if (Boolean.valueOf(env.UNIX)) {
        sh cmd
    }
    else {
        bat cmd
   }
}
```

Comment: Boolean.valueOf(env.UNIX) will convert the stringified "true" and "false" values.

Comment: There should be a default for this. Thx

Comment: If you use parallel jobs in your Jenkinsfile , be aware that `env` is a [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73402269/771768). If you assign `env.UNIX` from the start of each node, you'll have a **race condition** and it will fail the pipeline.