# Parallel matrix and global variables without race condition?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have the following declarative pipeline where I write a global `build` variable during a parallel matrix, the **write** in stage `Build Detection` is probably (wasn't clear to me) a **race condition** but I am not sure. I have 3 questions regarding the below simple pipeline:

1. Is it correct that since `Build-Detection` uses the same agent (note only `Build` uses a different agent), it is definitely a race condition ?
2. If I would have one agent for each parallel line, it would not be a race condition as the global `build` is different in each agent?
3. Is there a way to make a variable copy of `build` inside the stage such that it's not global any more?
4. How should we deal with global variable communicating stuff (for `when` steps etc) and parallel `matrix` feature?

```
Map<String,Boolean> build

pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      failFast false
      matrix {
        axes {
          axis {
            name 'CONTAINER'
            values 'A', 'B'
          }
        }
        stages {
          stage('Build Detection') {
            steps {
              script {
                build[CONTAINER] = CONATAINER == 'A'
                echo "Should Build: ${build[CONTAINER]}"
              }
            }
          }
          stage('Build') {
            agent {
              kubernetes {
                yamlFile '.jenkins/pods/build-kaniko.yaml'
              }
            }
            when {
              beforeAgent true
              expression { return build[CONTAINER] }
            }
            steps {
                echo "BUILDING....."
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. No, it has nothing to do with build agents. The JVM that's executing the compiled groovy code is running on the Jenkins master, not a build agent. Therefore, using a global variable is shared by each thread running in the Jenkins master JVM. Whether there's a possible race condition is not related to stages using the same or different build agents.
2. Same answer as 1.
3. Yes, simply define a variable using "def" or a specific type in the stage's script block. Just be sure to not reference a new variable without a type because in Groovy that causes it to be declared globally.
4. Using a map with a key that is specific to each thread like you're doing seems like a good way to me. If you really want to make sure there is no possibility of two unsafe thread operations modifying the map at the same time, then make sure that a threadsafe map is used. You could print out the class of the map to find out what implementation is getting instantiated. I would hope it's something threadsafe like [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).